# String compression implementation in C#

Tags: c#, strings, compression

I wrote a method that reduces a string like `aabcccccaaa` to `a2b1c5a3`

My implementation:

```
string Compress(string str)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    using(TextReader reader = new StringReader(str))
    {
        while(reader.Peek() != - 1){
            char c = (char)reader.Read();
            int n = 1;
            while(reader.Peek() == c) {
                reader.Read();
                n++;
            }
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}",c,n);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

What do you think about this, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looks fine. I'm sure you've already read the lit on the various ways of appending strings: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat  The only idea I had was maybe, this could be made faster by using memory stream and appending bytes. Strings have localization overhead, bytes wouldn't.

Comment: @MatthewMartin yeah replacing the using statement with this:  using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)))
    using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(ms)) would do the job but i'm not sure if it would be faster or not.

Comment: I put some more thought into this. To decompress & disambiguate from numbers (e.g. compress & decompress aaa1111111111111, a3113 => a(3113 times)) you'd need fixed width slots or a delimiter. And you could store the number in byte (1 byte to represent 256 instead of 3)

Comment: BTW, this operation is called *run-length encoding* (RLE).

Answer (score 11):

You can use a regular expression to match a range of repeated characters and replace it with the character and the count:

```
public static string Compress(string str) {
  return Regex.Replace(str, @"(.)\1*", m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Value.Length);
}
```

If that is better or not is up for debate, but it is at least a lot shorter.

You can also make it simpler using a regular loop and access the characters by index instead of using a `StringReader`. That makes it easier to compare the characters next to each other:

```
public static string Compress(string str) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 1, cnt = 1; i <= str.Length; i++, cnt++) {
    if (i == str.Length || str[i] != str[i - 1]) {
      builder.Append(str[i - 1]).Append(cnt);
      cnt = 0;
    }
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Huh, never knew `Regex.Replace` took a delegate. That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 8):

That's a perfectly cromulent implementation. I would just suggest making the style more consistent, with regards to spacing and braces, and maybe using `Append` instead of `AppendFormat`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using (var reader = new StringReader(str))
{
    while (reader.Peek() != -1)
    {
        char c = (char)reader.Read();
        int n = 1;
        while (reader.Peek() == c)
        {
            reader.Read();
            n++;
        }

        builder.Append(c).Append(n);
    }
}

return builder.ToString();
```

`StringReader` might be overkill for the situation; I find it to be of most use for its `ReadLine` method, which we're not using here. You might want to consider something like this:

```
var compressed = new StringBuilder();
int start = 0;
while (start < input.Length)
{
    char c = input[start];
    int end = start + 1;
    while (end < input.Length && input[end] == c)
    {
        end++;
    }

    compressed.Append(c).Append(end - start);
    start = end;
}

return compressed.ToString();
```

Comment: That's an option but i'm not sure if it would perform any better. StringReader just stores a reference to the string so there's no memory overhead.

Comment: @mjolka `builder.Append(c).Append(n);` this is delightful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the type of `String` that you wish to compress. If you are expecting multiple repeating characters then your system will work. However, if you wish to compress text, then this system will actually **increase** the size as few words have multiple repeating characters.

If you can **guarantee** that your string will be low-ASCII (no Unicode, no box-chars) then you can use the high-bit to signal your code to treat that character as a loop index.

```
if (c > 127) then n = c-127;
```

Also, you should be storing your repeat index as a value `'A'` not a string char `"65"`.

There are GNUish libraries available for RLE encoding, and it might be easier for you to use one of those.